# Upon retirement, what percentage of pornstars turn to religion, and which ones?

Tags: religion, sexuality, pornography

I have heard from word of mouth/gossip/etc. that many retired pornstars turn to religion after their careers are over. To what extent is this true? Is it uniform over sexes? Is it also the same for all religions? Does Buddhism maybe absorb more, or Christianity maybe?

I cannot find any statistics or studies on it, but there must be a lot of research on this. There has to be a percentage from countries, and an age graph and how this differs from a control group of random other groups of people.

Comment: I wouldn't be sure there's a lot of research on it.  Sometimes researchers seem to avoid the more lurid-sounding topics.

Comment: What is being posited (oh, and can you link to *anyone* claiming this?) has several flaws.  For instance, "turning to religion" implies that one was not already religious.  I'd guess that, but have no evidence to believe they're less religious than other groups.

Comment: When you say "turn to religion" you mean, what, exactly? Seek careers in the church, especially now that they're "retired?"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I doubt that is true. It is probably a claim that is being made because there's been a revival of "saving" hookers and other sex workers. One of the Poster children for it is Annie Lobert, who runs Hookers for Jesus. You can learn more about that [Here](http://sexandscience.org/blog/?p=473).

As far as I know, and I look for this kind of thing, there is no evidence to support the claim that people turn to religion at the end of their adult careers. In fact, while there is no evidence, I suspect the opposite is true. This could be because people are gradually disillusioned about things as their career progresses or, as often happens with most people, people become less religious with age. I can say that many people in the adult industry are already religious and justify their sex work for themselves when it conflicts with their religious ideas.

Basically, the best you have on this kind of thing is anecdote.

Comment: do remember that historically prostitution was often a religious rite. Priestess prostitutes existed in many old religions, and in some prostitution yourself in the temple was a rite of passage for a woman to reach adulthood (firewall here prevents me from looking up references :) ).